# Background Geolocation isn't a Observable

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic3

I need Implement a Background Geolocation in my app. I acess this [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-geolocation/), there shows the code below:

```
this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
  .subscribe((location: BackgroundGeolocationResponse) => {

    console.log(location);

    // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
    // and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your HTTP request is successful or not.
    // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
    this.backgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

  });
```

When I used this code in my app, my ts-lint accuse the  `configure(config)` method is a `Promise<any>` and not a `Observable`, so, I cant use `subscribe`. I switched `subscribe` for `then`. But when I run, shows this error below:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at BackgroundGeolocation.configure (vendor.js:82333)
// error below ommited
```

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the Plugin version. In Ionic 3 this versions work fine:

config.xml file:
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" spec="^2.2.5" />`

package.json file:
`"@ionic-native/background-geolocation": "^3.14.0",`

I found this answer in this [repository](https://github.com/jossephalvarez/backgroundGeo).

In the [Ionic v3 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/background-geolocation/) is wrong, because there says we need use this commands:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation@alpha
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation@4
```

But we need use this commands to work fine and finally use the `subscribe`:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation@2.2.5
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/background-geolocation@3
```

Comment: i have installed above but got another errror Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.?

Comment: You can try this two solutions: [first](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-broken-after-gradle-dependencies-update-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources-com-android-ide-common-process-processexception-failed-to-execute-aapt/109982) [second](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-error-eacces/110001)

Comment: sir 2nd solution worked for me but sir  if phone if lock that time "latitude and longitude" are not get after  change user position tell me sir what's the problem ?